# (extension)Saving the changed values when i updating the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

So, I have an input in `popup.html`. If you enter data, `popup.js` sends the data to `content.js` and it already changes something on tab. But after updating tab changes on the tab  is gone. How can you make it so that they would stay and change only if new data were entered into the `input`?

`popup.html и popup.js`

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#inp');
var text = document.querySelector("#text");
var button = document.querySelector("#btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var inp = input.value;

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(foundTabs) {

 const activeTab = foundTabs[0];

 chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {text: inp});//sending value of input
    })
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button id="btn">Send</button>
```

`content.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
     const txt  = request.text; //get input value
     chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
          //insert in html
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep the changes made, I would use `localStorage` (permanent) or `sessionStorage` (last as long as the window). With that, you can keep track of the changes made and re-make them when the webpage is updated.

For example:

**content.js**

```
//whenever the page is loaded/updated, check if there was a saved value
var my_text = sessionStorage.getItem("my_text");
if (my_text) {  // if there was, update the page accordingly.
  document.querySelector("input").value = my_text;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){  //when a message is received...
  my_text = message.text;
  document.querySelector("input").value = my_text;  //...update the webpage ...
  sessionStorage.setItem("my_text", my_text);  // ... and save the value
});
```

This way your changes will persist upon page reloads, until the window is closed. To make them persist even if the window is closed, substitute `sessionStorage` by `localStorage`.

Comment: So, all of this i must put into `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`?

Comment: No, you don't need `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`. All the code goes in `content.js` and is loaded (and reloaded) automatically in the webpage if you declare `content.js` in the `content_scripts` section of the `manifest.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

To save changes permanently you need to save the state somewhere.

For this purpose I recommend looking at [the Chrome developer background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

You can send a message from a background page to your [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), which is  `content.js`.